# HTML File Submission

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload

I'm using the follow code for a form to upload a file. As you can see, I have the actual "file" input hidden, and another, stylized text-box in it's place. What's happening, Is when you click the text box, it forwards the click to the "file" input. This works fine, It opens the dialog, and as i have it, it will update the text on the text-box. However, When I submit the form, php says there is no file. Is there something wrong with my HTML?..

```
<form class='uploadForm' action='uploader.php' method='POST' id='uploadForm' enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <h2>Upload an Image</h2>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td align='left'>
        <input type='text' name='name' placeholder='Name...' class='inputBox' id='name' />
      </td>
      <td align='right'>
        <input type='email' name='email' placeholder='Email...' class='inputBox' id='email' />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table style='color:#4D4D4D;'>
    <tr>
      <td style='padding:10px;' >
        <i align='left'>
          Max File Size: <b>2Mb</b> | Supported Formats: <b>jpg, jpeg, png, bmp</b>
        </i>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style='text-align:justify;white-space: nowrap;'>
        <input type="file" id="file" name="file" style="visibility: hidden; width: 1px; height: 1px" onchange='document.getElementById("upload").value = getFileName(document.getElementById("file").value);' />
        <input readonly type='text' class='uploadText' id='upload' placeholder='Click to select file...' onclick='document.getElementById("file").click(); return false;' />
        <a href='#' class="uploadButton" onclick='document.getElementById("uploadForm").submit();return false;'>Upload!</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

My PHP:

```
<?php print_r($_FILES); ?>
```

Output:

```
Array( )
```

Comment: How u are getting the file in PHP ?

Comment: I updated the post with the PHP code at the bottom

Comment: Yes saw it I just copied the code in my local and it works pretty well.

Comment: Then why am i getting 

Notice: Undefined index: file in S:\upl\uploader.php

Any time i try to access it?

Comment: his is what my print_r($_FILES) gave me Array ( [file] => Array ( [name] => API.doc [type] => application/msword [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpy1cKqH [error] => 0 [size] => 144896 ) ) ... make sure you have /temp folder with proper permission.

Comment: AH! I new i forgot to set something up. I just set it up. It's working fine. Thanks a million.